# gae ndb query failing to find related records with key property

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to implement a code which won't let an entity be deleted if it has any related entities.

```
class Father(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

class Son(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    father = ndb.KeyProperty(Father)
```

This is my code:

```
father = Father.get_by_id(long(keynumber))
if father:
    father_key = father.key
    if father_key:
        sons = Son.query(Son.father==father_key).fetch()
        number_of_sons = len(sons)
        if number_of_sons == 0:
            father_key.delete()
```

When this runs, sons is always an empty list [] although there are related sons to the father.

Why doesn't this query work?

Comment: Can you provide the code for how you populate your entities? It's possible that the `father` property is not populated correctly.

Also, your query for sons is [eventually consistent](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/). This means that you may get stale results from that query (or if the sons are relatively new, you may get no results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your help and posts.

I got it working by using this technique (aka workaround):

```
father = Father.get_by_id(long(keynumber))
if father:
    father_key = father.key
    if father_key:
        sons = Son.query(Son.father==ndb.Key('Father', str(keynumber))).fetch()
        number_of_sons = len(sons)
        if number_of_sons == 0:
            father_key.delete()
```

I still don't understand why but this worked for me.

Comment: You changed the Key so it uses `str(keynumber)`?  Is that also how you created the original entity?  You didn't mention this earlier, and would certainly explain why the query didn't work.

Comment: I think you're right... initially some of the Father entities ids were created explicitly as strings.  So perhaps this is why the query is needing string id values for the search.  My advice, in any case, would be to let ndb assign the id automatically from the start or, at least, to use numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

As @Patrick Costello suggests, using a [strongly-consistent](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) query is the right way to handle this:

```
class Father(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

class Son(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, father):
        son = cls(name=name, parent=father)
        son.put()
```

I would recommend using the [`count()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_count) operation:

```
father = Father.get_by_id(long(keynumber))
if father:
    father_key = father.key
    if father_key:
        sons_exist = Son.query(ancestor=father_key).count(1)
        if sons_exist == 0:
            father_key.delete()
```

By only counting up to 1, the result of `count(1)` is a true/false (1/0) value.

Not an exact duplicate, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353509/ndb-query-returns-zero-results-datastore-shows-the-result) is similar.

Comment: hmm I see, so the answer I proposed, which worked for me, at least in the tests I made, is bound to fail also, just because I'm not using this ancestor method to create the entities?

Comment: I just read Google's article about Structuring Data for Strong Consistency.  I think such strong consistency for being able to see changed information immediately does not apply in my case.  In my case, the data to be deleted will always have been created long ago.  Until now I have not had any issues using the workaround I suggested.  But I'll post any exception if it occurs.